# How to write NSConstraint visual format language by including another button's width plus a constant

Tags: ios, objective-c, nslayoutconstraint

In the [docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/VisualFormatLanguage/VisualFormatLanguage.html) about the visual format language for `NSLayoutConstraint` there is an example where you specify button1 is equal in width to button2:

```
[button1(==button2)]
```

my question: is there a way to make button1 equal to button 2's with + a constant.. I tried:

```
[button1(==button2+10)]
```

and

```
[button1(==(button2+10))]
```

and both failed.. here is an error example:

```
A predicate on a view's thickness must end with ')' and the view must end with ']' 
V:[tagWrapper(==tagButton+10)]
                         ^'
```

(I obviously know you can do this by doing an NSStringWithFormat and simply filling in the variable in question.. but that looks too messy)

ideas?

P.S. just in case you're curious why I would like to stick with visual format language (as opposed to the other ways of doing it like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20019764/766570) answer.. or using [wrapper libraries](https://github.com/smileyborg/UIView-AutoLayout) out there.. check out [this](https://gist.github.com/abbood/7500976) code sample)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some constraints can't be specified with the visual format language. You could use a simple constraint like this:

```
NSLayoutConstraint *c;
c = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:button1 
                                 attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth 
                                 relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                    toItem:button2 
                                 attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth
                                multiplier:1.0 
                                  constant:10.0];
```

Comment: umm.. simple yes.. verbose? even more yes.. i don't like this programmatic way of doing it.. i'm trying to stick with the visual format language.. much easier on the eyes

Comment: check out this [example](https://gist.github.com/abbood/7500976) to see why I insist on using visual format language.. Imagine if I had to write something like the above for *each* constraint

Comment: But you don't have to, just for those that can't be expressed with the visual format. And besides, you can always just put these into a nice category like `[button1 constraintWidthEqualTo:button2 constant:10];`

Comment: but then again.. they *can* be expressed with visual format.. if you look at my example you'll see that I actually did address my problem above.. with the slightly more verbose `NSStringWithFormat`

Comment: The problem with that is, it's not dynamic. Obviously you can hack together a format string that contains the correct width, but that width will be fixed, i.e. "make button1's width equal to 145 (which happens to be the width of button2 + 10)". If the width of button2 changes, button1 won't change, unless you recreate your constraints.

Comment: um.. i've never faced such a situation.. but I see that it's a very reasonable scenario.. and your point is well taken :).. but are you *sure* it's not dynamic?

Comment: Absolutely. You might construct your format string using a button's width, but at the end all Auto Layout sees is that you specify a constant width. It sort of defeats the purpose of Auto Layout.

Comment: @abbood Agreed, that's _not_ dynamic. And this is only one example of lots of different constraints that cannot be represented in VFL. Like DrummerB said, you can just write your own categories/methods to implement them if your code becomes unwieldy with all of the calls to `constraintWithItem`.

Comment: @abbood Visual format language. I don't know if it's an official Apple acronym, but you'll see it frequently here on Stack Overflow.