# How add fields programatically on UIscrollview using auto-layouts

Tags: ios, objective-c

Hi i am beginner in ios and in my project i am adding some fields on UIScrollview but fields are not fitting properly here i am creating scrollview and fields what i want to add on scrollview both are creating programatically using auto-layouts but scrollview is not scrolling and fields are not adding properly please help me some one

According to my code i am getting result second screen but i want to get result like first screen please help me some one

### This is my code

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];


    scrollview = [[UIScrollView alloc]init];
    [self.view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor darkGrayColor]];
    scrollview.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
    [scrollview setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:74.0/255.0 green:166.0/255.0 blue:224.0/255.0 alpha:1]];
    [self.view addSubview:scrollview];

    textFiedl1 = [[UITextField alloc]init];
    textFiedl1.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
    textFiedl1.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
    [scrollview addSubview:textFiedl1];

    textField2 = [[UITextField alloc]init];
    textField2.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
    textField2.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
    [scrollview addSubview:textField2];


    NSDictionary * views = NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(scrollview,textFiedl1,textField2);


    NSArray *horizontalConstraints =[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-10-[scrollview]-10-|"
                                                                            options:0
                                                                            metrics:nil
                                                                              views:views];

    NSArray *verticalConstraints = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|-20-[scrollview(280)]-|"
                                                                           options:0
                                                                           metrics:nil
                                                                             views:views];



    NSArray * textFieldConstraint1H = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-10-[textFiedl1]-10-|"
                                                                              options:0
                                                                              metrics:nil
                                                                                views:views];

    NSArray * textFieldConstraint2H = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-10-[textField2]-10-|"
                                                                              options:0
                                                                              metrics:nil
                                                                                views:views];


    NSArray * textFieldConstraintV = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|-20-[textFiedl1(30)]-30-[textField2(30)]"
                                                                             options:0
                                                                             metrics:nil
                                                                               views:views];

    [self.view addConstraints:horizontalConstraints];
    [self.view addConstraints:verticalConstraints];
    [scrollview addConstraints:textFieldConstraint1H];
    [scrollview addConstraints:textFieldConstraint2H];
    [scrollview addConstraints:textFieldConstraintV];

    //set content size
    [scrollview setContentSize:CGSizeMake(100, 700)];
}
```

But i want to get result like first screen shot(and one more thing here scrollview is not scrolling even i set contentoffset(100X700)

[image]

[image]

Comment: Let me guess, you want to dynamically add textfield to scrollview??

Answer (score 0):

You could add a container view into you scrollview to active scrollview. Addition, it would be easier to controller constrains subview of scrollview

```
UIView *containerView = [[UIView alloc] init];
containerView.backgroundColor = [UIColor yellowColor]; // just so I can see it
containerView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
[scrollview addSubview:containerView];
NSDictionary * views = NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(scrollview,textFiedl1,textField2,view,containerView);


NSArray *horizontalConstraints =[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-10-[scrollview]-10-|"
                                                                        options:0
                                                                        metrics:nil
                                                                          views:views];

NSArray *verticalConstraints = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|-20-[scrollview(280)]-|"
                                                                       options:0
                                                                       metrics:nil
                                                                         views:views];

// set the container to the size of the main view, and simultaneously
// set the scrollview's contentSize to match the size of the container

[view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|[containerView(==scrollview)]|"
                                                             options:0
                                                             metrics:nil
                                                               views:views]];

[view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|-20-[containerView(==view)]|"
                                                             options:0
                                                             metrics:nil
                                                               views:views]];



NSArray * textFieldConstraint1H = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-10-[textFiedl1]-10-|"
                                                                          options:0
                                                                          metrics:nil
                                                                            views:views];

NSArray * textFieldConstraint2H = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-10-[textField2]-10-|"
                                                                          options:0
                                                                          metrics:nil
                                                                            views:views];


NSArray * textFieldConstraintV = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|-20-[textFiedl1(30)]-30-[textField2(30)]"
                                                                         options:0
                                                                         metrics:nil
                                                                           views:views];

[view addConstraints:horizontalConstraints];
[view addConstraints:verticalConstraints];
[containerView addConstraints:textFieldConstraint1H];
[containerView addConstraints:textFieldConstraint2H];
[containerView addConstraints:textFieldConstraintV];

//setting content size now no longer needed in autolayout.
//[scrollview setContentSize:CGSizeMake(100, 700)];
```

Comment: [scrollview setContentSize:CGSizeMake(100, 700)]; not working

Comment: If you using Autolayout, it is no need to set ContentSize because it will be calculate automatically. In your case, you just add more text field to containerview and extend containerview's frame size, scrollview will automatically calculate your content size and allow you scrolling down. No need using [scrollview setContentSize:] anymore

Answer (score 0):

You have some issues with your constraints. Modified as below, the scrollview will scroll, and the textfield will have a fix width (Please check comment in the code):

```
UIScrollView *scrollview = [[UIScrollView alloc]init];
[self.view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor darkGrayColor]];
scrollview.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
[scrollview setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:74.0/255.0 green:166.0/255.0 blue:224.0/255.0 alpha:1]];
[self.view addSubview:scrollview];

UITextField *textFiedl1 = [[UITextField alloc]init];
textFiedl1.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
textFiedl1.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
[scrollview addSubview:textFiedl1];

UITextField *textField2 = [[UITextField alloc]init];
textField2.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
textField2.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
[scrollview addSubview:textField2];


NSDictionary * views = NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(scrollview,textFiedl1,textField2);


NSArray *horizontalConstraints =[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-10-[scrollview]-10-|"
                                                                        options:0
                                                                        metrics:nil
                                                                          views:views];

NSArray *verticalConstraints = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|-20-[scrollview(280)]"
                                                                       options:0
                                                                       metrics:nil
                                                                         views:views];



// you must provide the autolayout system some hint about the width
// of the content of the scrollView.
// Here we set a fixed width to textField.
NSArray * textFieldConstraint1H = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-10-[textFiedl1(100)]-10-|"
                                                                          options:0
                                                                          metrics:nil
                                                                            views:views];

NSArray * textFieldConstraint2H = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-10-[textField2]-10-|"
                                                                          options:0
                                                                          metrics:nil
                                                                            views:views];


// In order for the scrollView to scroll, you must setup
// vertical constraints such that the height of scrollView's content height can be determined
// Here we add a constraints to set textField2 bottom to scrollView bottom(200).
NSArray * textFieldConstraintV = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|-20-[textFiedl1(30)]-30-[textField2(30)]-200-|"
                                                                         options:0
                                                                         metrics:nil
                                                                           views:views];

[self.view addConstraints:horizontalConstraints];
[self.view addConstraints:verticalConstraints];
[scrollview addConstraints:textFieldConstraint1H];
[scrollview addConstraints:textFieldConstraint2H];
[scrollview addConstraints:textFieldConstraintV];

//set content size
[scrollview setContentSize:CGSizeMake(100, 700)];
```

However, if you want to add some padding between textfield and the scrollview, as described in your image, I think you can not do that with visual format constraints. You could use simple constraints describe [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20019730/how-to-write-nsconstraint-visual-format-language-by-including-another-buttons-w).

Also, you can use the [Masonry](https://github.com/SnapKit/Masonry) library, which provide much simpler syntax to setup constraints programatically.

Comment: i want to set that text-fields in all i phone inches Jakehao(i mean that fields need to set for portraint@landscape modes in all i phone inches )

Comment: I see, that's why I include the link here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20019730/how-to-write-nsconstraint-visual-format-language-by-including-another-buttons-w